# Como genero un .jar en eclipse con todas las librerias

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

necesito generar un .jar en eclipse pero esta depende de unas librerias y cuando lo exporto y utilizo me menciona que no encuentra la libreria que se necesita, alguien podria ayudarme, de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Como estas generando el jar? Añade un poco mas de detalles

Comment: Lo genero con eclipse, simplemente le doy exportar y sigo las instrucciones y me lo genera pero al parecer no agrega el otro .jar que importo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.- Debes hacer click derecho sobre el proyecto luego Export

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2.- Seleccionar Runnable Jar File

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3.- Debes dejar todo igual a la foto :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nota : Jar File y Runnable son muy similares asi que no le des enfasis a eso .

Espero sea de ayuda
Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

No tengo mucho contexto de como generas el .jar pero si te sirve yo lo genero de la siguiente manera y no he tenido ningún problema por cuestiones de librerias:

- `File > Export` se elige la opción:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Se le da `Next` y te da las siguientes opciones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- En `Launch Configuration` se elije la clase principal del .jar a ejecutar(la que tiene el main), `Export destination` es la ruta donde va hacer generado el JAR y se selecciona el `Extract required linreries into generated JAR`

Espero te pueda servir, como te comento no hay muchos detalles de lo que deseas realizar.